# I update the picture with the spatie media library and my picture does not appear

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

*my controller:*

```
    public function update(SettingUpdateRequest $request, Setting $id){

    $setting = Setting::first();

   $setting->update($request->post());

    if ($request->hasFile('site_logo')) {
        $setting->addMedia($request->site_logo)->toMediaCollection('document');
    }
    return redirect()
        ->route('back.setting.index')->withMessage('Ayarlar başarıyla güncellendi!');

}
```

*my model:*

```
    namespace App\Models;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
   use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
   use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

class Setting extends Model implements HasMedia
{
use HasFactory , InteractsWithMedia;
protected $table='settings';
protected $fillable=['site_title','site_desc','site_email'];
protected $appends = ['site_logo'];


public function getSiteLogoAttribute()
{
    return $this->getMedia('document')->last();
}
}
```

*my picture way in stroge:*
**https://prnt.sc/11q22mc**

*my blade:*

```
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputFile">Site Logo</label>
   <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="site_logo" class="form-control" accept="image/*">
   </div>
   <label><strong>Resimler:</strong></label>
    @if (!$setting->site_logo)
    <span class="form-text text-muted">Bu Rehber ile ilgili resim bulunamadı. Yeni bir resim ekleyin! 
    </span>
    @endif
   <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="image-input image-input-empty image-input-outline" id="kt_image_5" style="background-image: url({{$setting->getFirstMediaUrl('document')}})">
    <div class="image-input-wrapper"></div>

    <span class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-white btn-hover-text-primary btn-shadow" data-action="cancel" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Cancel avatar">
        <i class="ki ki-bold-close icon-xs text-muted"></i>
   </span>
       <span class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-white btn-hover-text-primary btn-shadow" data-action="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Remove avatar">
     </span>
     </div>
   </div>
```

*my database:*
**https://prnt.sc/11q2b2l**

*I update the picture with the spatie media library and my picture does not appear.*

**https://prnt.sc/11q2fvi**
*my console fault:*
**https://prnt.sc/11q2k8q**

Comment: Can you add a `@dd($setting->getFirstMediaUrl('document'))` in your blade and show us the result?

Comment: when I use it, https://prnt.sc/11qtzgs show

Comment: It looks good. Can you see that url which is in the black box in your browser?

Comment: No, it warns that this site cannot be reached

Comment: does not update when adding pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should retrieve the last media in your blade. As you've already defined a getter in your model, you can use below code.

```
{{ $setting->site_logo->getUrl() }}
```

Comment: This time he is updating, but when he goes to that address, the picture cannot be accessed.

Comment: You must be sure about existing this `'links' => [public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public')],` at the end of your `config/filesystems.php` file and running `php artisan config:clear` and  `php artisan storage:link` in the console.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/11qy5gv  php artisan storage:link I did it before.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/12/resim5.jpg11 When I type 127.0.0.1:8000 instead of localhost, the picture comes up. But my extension comes as localhost, how can I change it.

Comment: Change `APP_URL` in your **.env** to `127.0.0.1:8000`

Answer (score 1):

you should delete last image

```
                $setting->media()->delete();
```

or you can use

```
 $setting->clearMediaCollection('document');
```